# Django ValueError - not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) list of tuples error

Tags: python, django

This is what is causing the error, I know that much:

forms.py file:

```
class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    ENGLISH_INTEREST = EnglishInterest.get_english_interest_data()

    english_interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ENGLISH_INTEREST, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

models.py file:

```
class EnglishInterest(models.Model):
    english_interest = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @staticmethod
    def get_english_interest_data():
        return EnglishInterest.objects.values_list('english_interest')
```

I know there must be some simple solution to get this multiple choice field to work. It does work if I were to use instead:

```
ENGLISH_INTEREST= [
('general speaking', 'General Speaking'),
('work opportunities', 'Work Opportunities'),
('travel', 'Travel'),
('study abroad', 'Study Abroad'),
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to show dynamic choice fields in your form, which updates based on inserts into `EnglishInterest` Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choice fields need an id and a display name. Usually you can just directly pass it a queryset but you can also pass a list of tuples.

```
choices = [(0, 'Choice 1'), (1, 'Choice 2')]
```

In your case you need to make a small change to include the id field in the values list

```
def get_english_interest_data(self):
    return EnglishInterest.objects.values_list('id', 'english_interest')
```